# Como realizar um Migration em Laravel, sem excluir as demais tabelas

Tags: php, laravel, aplicação-web, migrations

sou novo tanto no Laravel, quanto aqui no Stack, recentemente estou montando um sistema e dentro do processo esqueci de colocar um migration.

Normalmente eu coloco o comando `php artisan migrate:refresh`, entretanto todos os dados que estavam usando como teste eles são resetados. A solução q eu encontrei é gerar a tabela automaticamente no MySQL, mas leva um pouco de tempo.

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de gerar a tabela do migrate, sem zerar os dados preenchidos.

Comment: Já tentou rodar só php artisan migrate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível executar o `php artisan migrate:refresh` sem apagar os dados, pois o [refresh](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#running-migrations) recria as entidades do banco de dados.

Você pode usar [Seeds e Factories](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/seeding) para popular a base de dados com exemplos usando `--seed`

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed
```

Se você quiser adicionar uma nova migration, não é necessário usar o refresh, use apenas o `php artisan migrate`, seus dados serão mantidos e a nova entidade será criada normalmente